# Opening client side applications via a remote app

Tags: ms-access, outlook, rdp

Ive done a fair amount of searching on this, but ive struggled to find the answer.

At present I have an access program that sits on a remote windows 2008 server and users can log into it through a remote app. In the local version of my program, users can hit a button and email through outlook, but obviously if your accessing it remotely it tries to open outlook remotely.

So here's the question: Is there any functionality that will allow me to open Outlook locally whilst using the remote app?

Ive read about scriptable virtual channels but i would like someone to confirm if this is possible (or call me a moron for even contemplating the idea).

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Split the database. Your client will then open Outlook locally.

Here is some info that might be helpful if you do not know how to split the database and what the benefits are: http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/split-an-access-database-HA010342026.aspx